# Notes window that always stays in front

Tags: windows

I want a transparent notes window that always stays in front. I'll use it to put 2 or 3 daily reminders.

I tried the Window's Sticky Notes app and it isn't transparent and it doesn't stay in front of the other windows.

Answer (score 2):

There's a paid software called [Notezilla](https://www.conceptworld.com/Notezilla/Download) which does this. They offer a 30-day free trial.

[image]

[A review from pcworld.com](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2855027/notezilla-8-review-this-monster-crushes-other-note-programs-like-its-namesake-crushes-tokyo.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Stickies](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/index.html) from personal experience.

It's a free "sticky" editor similar to the Windows built-in, with a bunch of additional features. Note transparency and always on top per sticky is possible.

> Main features
> -
>
> - Once on screen, notes will remain where placed until closed, even through reboots
> - Stickies appearance can be customised; fonts, colours and buttons may be changed, and styles saved. Notes can be resized.
> - Stickies can store text or images
> - Stickies can be hidden for a certain period, until a specified date and time, or to wake every day, week or month, to act as reminders.
> - Stickies can have alarms set to ensure you notice them at a point you choose
> - International language, Unicode and RTL text support
> - Stickies can snap to each other and to the sides of the screen to keep them neatly lined up
> - Stickies can be attached to an application, web site, document or folder so they only show when it's on screen
> - Stickies can be transferred from one machine to another either over a TCP/IP network connection, or by using an SMTP mail server or MAPI client:
> - Hierarchical friends list, which may be automatically transferred from other friends
> - Stickies works with Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10
> - Stickies is small and simple, it writes to a database file, and does not alter the registry
> - AD network administrators can use Group Policy to control settings
> - API to allow integration with other applications
> - ...and Stickies is completely free!